# Appium + Java + Android + Mobile browser [Chrome driver] : How to switch from android app to mobile browser?

Tags: java, android, appium, chromedriver, mobile-automation

I am automating android app. My env is - Mac, Appium, Java + TestNG

Scenario:

1. Click on button
2. Its will redirect user on mobile browser
3. Login in browser

How to automate above scenario? The core question where I am facing issue is - Once redirected on mobile browser can, I am unable to take actions of elements.

Q - How to switch from android app to mobile browser?